# on_member_join() missing one keyword-only argument: 'member'

Tags: discord.py

So I am making a welcome command that looks as follows:

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_join(self, *, member: discord.Member):
meant = member.mention
    member = discord.Guild.member
    guild = discord.Guild
    welcomz = [
        ', welcome to the server!',
        ' joined the party!',
        ' came just for the cake.',
        ', everyone welcomes you to the server!',
        ', go do some stuff here.',
        ', so you do know how an invite link works!',
        ', took you long enough!',
    ]
    try:
        await self.client.get_channel(guild.text_channel.id).send(f"{meant}" + random.choice(welcomz))
    except:
        print(f"Error occurred when welcoming member:{meant}")
```

and it comes up with the error.
I am not totally sure what is wrong.

Comment: [`on_member_join()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_member_join#discord.on_member_join) takes 1 argument, you gave like 3 (`self`, `*`, and `member: discord.Member`) while there should be one eg. `on_member_join(member)`. Also, you should maybe use self while in a '[Cog](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/cogs.html)' or in a [class object](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html). You don't need `:discord.Member` after the member argument because it'll return a member object anyway.

Comment: It gives an error when I remove it

Comment: You shouldn't be getting an error. You must have done something else wrong, what does the error say?

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at the [`discord.py`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) documentation. The [`on_member_join()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_member_join#discord.on_member_join) event only takes one parameter and it's `member`.

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    channel = client.get_channel(730064641857683581)  # ID for your welcome channel.
    welcomz = [
        ', welcome to the server!',
        ' joined the party!',
        ' came just for the cake.',
        ', everyone welcomes you to the server!',
        ', go do some stuff here.',
        ', so you do know how an invite link works!',
        ', took you long enough!',
    ]
    try:
        await channel.send(f"{member.mention}, {random.choice(welcomz)}")
    except:
        print(f"Error occurred when welcoming member: {member}")
```